# Should glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) be applied per texture unit

Tags: opengl

In OpenGL I have always understood that `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_1D)`, `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` and/or `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_3D)` (and corresponding `glDisable`) is a per texture unit parameter.

Recently I tried to confirm this but have not found any clear documentation confirming either way regarding this question.

Put simply and in code, should I be doing this

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
... bind etc ... 

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
... bind etc ...
```

or this

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
... bind etc ...

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
.... bind etc ...
```

I was hoping to find some clarity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is indeed per texture unit. The most recent documentation I found mentioning this explicitly was the Open GL specification 2.1 (2006 update) [here](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec21.20061201.pdf)

In section 3.8.16: **Texture Application**

It is probably mentioned somewhere in the new specifications but they were heavy re-organized. You can have a look at all the Open GL version specifications on the opengl org website (I wanted to post a link but I can't seem to post more than one).

Comment: Well, actually, it's not going to be in the latest core revisions because fixed-function was deprecated and then removed, and the Enable is controlling the fixed-function state. It does not have any effect on shaders.

Comment: @Bahbar: Do you mean the GLSL shaders with their annotations can control the state of the texture units and samplers and thus there is no need for an explicit glEnable(GL_TEXTURE2D) for example?

Answer (score 8):

It's per texture unit.

From the GL1.5 specification, 3.8.15:

> Each texture unit is enabled and bound
>   to texture objects independently from
>   the other texture units

Answer (score 3):

If you use `GLSL` shaders in OpenGL the call `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE)` has not influence.

Furthermore, if you intend to move on to the OpenGL 3.x core profile keep in mind that `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE)` is deprecated.

Comment: `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` is still having an effect in my code, despite only shader code. It appears that calls to `glBindTexture` change behavior... This would be OpenGL 3.2 core profile.