# GLFW GLAD Texture not drawn, black square

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, glad

I am trying to draw a texture to a square made out of two triangles. However, instead of showing a square with a texture it shows, a black square. Also, shader.h works perfectly with colors. This is not all of the code from main.cpp, just the texture code.

Main.cpp

```cpp
    Shader defShader("resources/shaders/vertex.txt", "resources/shaders/fragment.txt");

    float vertices[] = {
        0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,  1.0f,1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,  1.0f,0.0f,
        -0.5f,-0.5f, 0.0f,  1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,  0.0f,1.0f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,  1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,  0.0f,1.0f
    };

    unsigned int indices[] = {
        0,1,3,
        1,2,3
    };
    unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    unsigned int texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    // Set texture wrap parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // Set texture filtering paremeters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // Load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
    int w, h, nrChannels;

    unsigned char *data = stbi_load("resources/textures/wall.jpg", &w, &h, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data) {
        std::cout << "LOADING TEXTURE\n" << std::endl;
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "FAILED TO LOAD TEXTURE\n" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        processInput(window);

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Render stuff
        defShader.Use();
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the shaders.
vertShader.txt

```c
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    ourColor = aColor;
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

fragShader.txt

```c
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture;

void main() {
    FragColor = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord);
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041124/should-glenablegl-texture-2d-be-applied-per-texture-unit if not, you should try to take a capture with a tool such as renderdoc

Comment: Why don't you ever re-bind your texture object before drawing?

Comment: @genpfault how do I do that?

Comment: @Borgleader how do I use renderdoc?

Comment: Same way you did to upload the texture image: `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)`.

Comment: @genpfault where do I put it? Before glDrawElements? Sorry I am very new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

- Set `stbi_load()`'s `desired_channels` to `3` instead of just hoping the image is 3-channel.
- Set `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` in case the loaded image doesn't match up with the default of `4`.
- You're unbinding the texture object right after you load it; make sure to re-bind it before you draw.
- Use `stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1)` (or modify your texcoords) to flip the image the 'right' way around for OpenGL.
- Your vertex/texcoords/indexes were a bit wonky; I fixed them up to make sense to me.
- You really ought to set which particular texture unit your shader should be sampling from instead of relying on the fact unassigned sampler uniforms default to zero:

  ```
  unsigned int texture_unit = 0;
  glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 + texture_unit );
  glUniform1i( glGetUniformLocation( prog, "ourTexture" ), texture_unit );
  ```

All together:

[image: screenshot]

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

void CheckStatus( GLuint obj, bool isShader )
{
    GLint status = GL_FALSE, log[ 1 << 11 ] = { 0 };
    ( isShader ? glGetShaderiv : glGetProgramiv )( obj, isShader ? GL_COMPILE_STATUS : GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
    if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
    ( isShader ? glGetShaderInfoLog : glGetProgramInfoLog )( obj, sizeof( log ), NULL, (GLchar*)log );
    std::cerr << (GLchar*)log << "\n";
    std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
    glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
    glCompileShader( shader );
    CheckStatus( shader, true );
    glAttachShader( program, shader );
    glDeleteShader( shader );
}

const char* vert = 1 + R"GLSL(
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    ourColor = aColor;
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
)GLSL";

const char* frag = 1 + R"GLSL(
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture;

void main() {
    FragColor = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord);
}
)GLSL";

int main( int, char** )
{
    glfwSetErrorCallback( []( int, const char* desc ) { std::cerr << desc << "\n"; std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); } );
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow( 640, 480, "GLFW", NULL, NULL );
    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );
    gladLoadGLLoader( (GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress );

    GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
    AttachShader( prog, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vert );
    AttachShader( prog, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, frag );
    glLinkProgram( prog );
    CheckStatus( prog, false );

    float vertices[] =
    {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,  0.0f,0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,  1.0f,0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,  1.0f,1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,  0.0f,1.0f
    };

    unsigned int indices[] =
    {
        0,1,2,
        2,3,0
    };
    unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    unsigned int texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    // Set texture wrap parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // Set texture filtering paremeters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // Load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
    int w, h;

    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load( 1 );
    // https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/Brick_wall_close-up_view.jpg/800px-Brick_wall_close-up_view.jpg
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load("wall.jpg", &w, &h, NULL, 3);
    if (data)
    {
        std::cout << "LOADING TEXTURE: " << w << "x" << h << std::endl;
        glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1 );
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "FAILED TO LOAD TEXTURE\n" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Render stuff
        glUseProgram( prog );
        unsigned int texture_unit = 0;
        glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 + texture_unit );
        glUniform1i( glGetUniformLocation( prog, "ourTexture" ), texture_unit );
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}
```